# NSUnderlineStyleSingle underlines more than range of the text

Tags: ios, hyperlink, nsrange, nsmutableattributedstring

I have implemented underline of mutableattributedtext, have set the range also correctly, but it still underlines more than the range specified and instead fills the text box it is contained in.

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0,[attributedString length])];
```

I want this to happen.
[image: I want to this type of hyperlink creation][image: But I receive this as a result of the above code]

But Instead I get this.

Comment: Problem is your text is multiline and your rang is  NSMakeRange(0,[attributedString length] that means to the end of the text. you need to handle line break characters and define your range accordingly.

Comment: Every word is taken as portionString so attributedString is "ABC" "corporation" etc, so attributedString length gives me individual length of the strings.